# Difference between EJB @Remote ( javax.ejb.Remote ) and RMI ( java.rmi.Remote )

Tags: java, ejb, components, protocols, rmi

I would like to know the differences between **EJB @Remote components** and **RMI components**.

I have done a lot of researches but I didn't find enough informations about EJB @Remote (maybe because there are not very used).

1. Are EJB @Remote ([javax.ejb.Remote](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Remote.html)) and RMI ([java.rmi.Remote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/Remote.html)) the
   same thing but with alternative syntaxes, or have they totally different purpose ?
2. I suppose default port for EJB @Remote and RMI are the same (1099). I know how to configure port number for RMI service, but I don't know how to do it for EJB @Remote, is there a standard way to configure it ?
3. What protocol does EJB @Remote use ? RMI-JRMP or RMI-IIOP ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you find an answer for this?

Comment: Hi, I made a lot of researches but unfortunately no, I didn't find real answers to those questions. I read somewhere that when you create an EJB (*@Stateless*, *@Stateful*, *@Singleton*) this EJB is *@Local* by default, and it's only accessible to the clients which are executed from the same JVM, but if we want to use this EJB from another JVM, we have to annotate our EJB with *@Remote* (it uses serialization, therefore there's an impact on performance).